# Couldn't list the pages from facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

My code

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' =>  $config['fb_api'],
'app_secret' =>  $config['fb_secret'],
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
'cookie' => false,
]);
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$accounts = $facebook->get('/me/accounts',$access_token);
```

When i checked `$accounts = $accounts->getDecodedBody();` it returns null although i can see my fb pages through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.10 link.

**However,I have my access token in `$access_token`**

Comment: Does your access token include the required permission? (Go debug it to find out, if you are not sure.)

Comment: yeah recently i change my `default_graph_version` to `v2.4` and it worked. If i switch between graph version of api do i have to remove the api from my facebook settings as well?

Comment: There is no setting for the API version in app dashboard, it only shows what the minimal API version your app can use is.

Comment: some times while connecting fb account access token is null and if i switch that graph version then suddenly it will work. what is the cause?